# Pass a i18n text as component parameter in Angular2

Tags: angular, internationalization

I want to inject a translated text into a component.

```
<my-component [text]="_A_TRANSLATED_TEXT_" />
```

Following the doc, https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/i18n.html, I don't find this kind of basic feature. 
Any idea how to do?

Thank

Answer (score 4):

It seems possible to use this kind of syntax

```
<app-mycomp 
    i18n 
    param="my param" i18n-param
    another_param="my param" i18n-another_param>
my text
</app-mycomp>
```

So i18n will affect to content of the tag, and i18n-* will affect the corresponding attribute.
Seem not documented yet.